# Find and return the ReceivedTime of the oldest email from outlook in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook, mapi

Ok so far I am able to display the oldest unread but not the overall oldest email. When I do it halts the program of course.

```
        Dim objOutlook As Outlook._Application
    objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim objNS As Outlook._NameSpace = objOutlook.Session
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient = _
        objNS.CreateRecipient("John Smith")
   'Dim eMail As Outlook.MailItem
    'Dim travelunreadold As String
    Dim vItems
    Dim vvItems
    Dim vOlderItems
    Dim vOlderunreadItems

    If objRecipient.Resolve Then
        Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = _
            objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, _
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
        txtTravUnread.Text = objFolder.UnReadItemCount

        'For Each eMail In objFolder.Items
        '    If eMail.UnRead = True Then
        '        travelunreadold = eMail.ReceivedTime
        '        Txttravundate.Text = travelunreadold
        '    End If

        'Next eMail
        vItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
        vItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", False) 'ascending order
        vOlderunreadItems = vItems.GetFirst
        Txttravundate.Text = vOlderunreadItems

        vvItems = objFolder.Items
        vvItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", False) 'ascending order
        vOlderItems = vvItems.GetFirst
        Txttravemdate.Text = vOlderItems

        txtTravEmails.Text = objFolder.Items.Count
        'Txttravemdate.Text = oldest.recievedtime

    Else
        Console.Write("Recipient could not be resolved.")
    End If
```

I have edited with the changes provided. Seems that its not grabbing the dates, however the program doesn't hang as long as it was with the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, do not loop through all items in a folder. It is extremely inefficient. Use Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict.

In your case (oldest email), use Items.Sort:

```
set vItems = objFolder.Items
vItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", false 'ascending order
set vOlderItems = vItems.GetFirst
```

If you only want the oldest unread emails, use Restrict:

```
set vItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true ")
vItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", false 'ascending order
set vOlderItems = vItems.GetFirst
```

Comment: The loop is for the unread emails so I should go ahead and do this for the unread as well. Because in the end I need the oldest unread and the oldest overall

Comment: If you only want unread messages, see the updated answer above.

Comment: So I can just use those both and change the variable names cause I need to grab them both and use them in the same process.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use both.

Comment: I cant use set so I am using dim aside from that nothing different and its not working.

Comment: You can use "set"? Why can't you? What exactly does not work when you step through your code?

Comment: When I put set it comes up with something else and when pasting it, it removes the set. And none of it works, what I need it to do is put the receivedtime of the oldest and the unread oldest and put each in their own text boxes. It will put the total amount of bo in its textbox just not the dates.

Comment: It finally allowed me to edit it. Said I didn't have enough text outside of the code sorry.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What do you see as you step through the code? I'd replace Txttravundate.Text = vOlderunreadItems with Txttravundate.Text = vOlderunreadItems.Subject. Same with Txttravemdate.

Comment: Adding the .subject gave me the subject of the email switching that to recievedtime makes it go blank and during runtime I see this show up in the immediate window A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: And look at the value of the Class property.

Comment: vItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
        vItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", False) 'ascending order
        vOlderunreadItems = vItems.GetFirst
        Txttravundate.Text = vOlderunreadItems
is where is stops working.

Comment: Were you not gong to change that to something like this? Txttravundate.Text = FormatDateTime(vOlderunreadItems.ReceivedTime, 0) ?

Comment: Yup that was it. Got ahead of myself. Thanks!

Comment: Please mark as answered if the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dmitry it is working with the following changes

```
        Dim objOutlook As Outlook._Application
    objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()
    Dim objNS As Outlook._NameSpace = objOutlook.Session
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient = _
        objNS.CreateRecipient("John Smith")
    '  Dim eMail As Outlook.MailItem
    ' Dim travelunreadold As String
    Dim vItems
    Dim vvItems
    Dim vOlderItems
    Dim vOlderunreadItems

    If objRecipient.Resolve Then
        Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = _
            objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, _
            Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
        txtTravUnread.Text = objFolder.UnReadItemCount
        txtTravEmails.Text = objFolder.Items.Count
        'For Each eMail In objFolder.Items
        '    If eMail.UnRead = True Then
        '        travelunreadold = eMail.ReceivedTime
        '        Txttravundate.Text = travelunreadold
        '    End If

        'Next eMail
        vvItems = objFolder.Items
        vvItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", False) 'ascending order
        vOlderItems = vvItems.GetFirst
        Txttravemdate.Text = FormatDateTime(vOlderItems.ReceivedTime, 0)


        vItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
        vItems.Sort("ReceivedTime", False) 'ascending order
        vOlderunreadItems = vItems.GetFirst
        Txttravundate.Text = FormatDateTime(vOlderunreadItems.ReceivedTime, 0)


        'Txttravemdate.Text = oldest.recievedtime

    Else
        Console.Write("Recipient could not be resolved.")
    End If
```